# Unable to create a Orchestrating Function in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I have started to get my hands dirty on azure function. I am trying to implement [this example](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Understanding-Azure-Durable-Functions-Part-2-Creating-Your-First-Durable-Function) in `.net 7.0`. In the azure function list, I was unable to find "Durable Functions Orchestration" option, but I went ahead and started copy-pasting from the link. Right now, I am stuck on the last piece of the code. Please help me out, what shall be done here. Screenshot attached

[image: First Part of the code]

[image: Help me in the red highlighted part]

Comment: Is that .NET 7 Isolated because .NET 7 not yet released. And If .NET 7 Isolated, there is no Durable Functions Option in VS 2022 - https://i.imgur.com/GqSOVvp.png

Comment: @HariKrishna, Can you provide any link for your claim ?

Comment: https://tech.playgokids.com/azure-durable-functions-net7-out-of-process/

Comment: I found only 3 references. One is the article given by Silent user and the second one is Azure Functions Tech Community Update [Doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916) and the other is .NET 7 Azure Durable Functions [Conf Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/dotnetconf-2022/using-durable-azure-functions-in-dotnet-7)

Answer (score 1):

.NET 7 is not yet released and for .NET 7 Isolated, below are the available Function Triggers and Durable Functions did not come yet, still in beta:

[image]

> Can you provide any link for your claim ?

I have found 3 references. One is the [PlaygokidsTech's article](https://tech.playgokids.com/azure-durable-functions-net7-out-of-process/) given by Silent user where the article explains key changes in .NET 7 Isolated worker project in the context of Durable Functions.

And the second one is Azure Functions Tech Community Update [Doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916) and the other is .NET 7 Azure Durable Functions [Conference Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/dotnetconf-2022/using-durable-azure-functions-in-dotnet-7)